# A/C capacitor replacement

Tags: hvac

Can a CBB65 55+15uF+/-5% 250VAC 40/70/21 dual capacitor in a window mounted a/c unit be replaced with a 50+15uF +/-5% 250 VAC 40/70/21 safely?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. My guess is "yes", but there's no way to tell without talking to an electrical engineer, who don't usually hang out here. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can be +/- 10% off on the uF rating and it'll work. I'd definitely make a label on or inside the unit to remind you what the original dual capacitor's rating was so you don't forget in the future.

These things are cheap, so just replace with the one you have for now to get it working, order the correct part, then swap them once it arrives and keep the wrong size around as a spare again.